# How to update table using BindingSource

Tags: vb.net

The following code throws: There is no row at position 54. This happens only when a new record is inserted. In edit mode it works fine.

row = Me.StockTranBindingNavigator.BindingSource.Position
Me.DataSet1.Tables("StockTran").Rows(row).Item("CostPrice") = "1275"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like :

```
    Dim row As Integer = BindingSource1.Position
    Dim drv As DataRowView = BindingSource1.Current
    drv("CostPrice") = "1275"
    BindingSource1.EndEdit()
```